# How to add a caption before tabularx? \captionof{table}{11111}\label{11} and \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth} is causing my indentation issues

Tags: tabularx, indentation, captionof

Indentation is normal before this code(`\captionof{table}{111}`) and disappears after this code.
When I delete it, indentation is normal.
So, how to add a title(caption) for this tabularx?

```
%\usepackage{indentfirst}%doesn't do anything to solve the problem
%\setlength{\parindent}{2em}%doesn't do anything to solve the problem

\noindent\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\captionof{table}{11111}\label{11}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sssbbbs}
    \toprule
    11   & 111  & 11  & 1111  & 11  & 11   & 11  \\ [0.5ex]
    \midrule
111   & 111 & 2020 & 111 & 111  & 111  & 111  \\
111 & 111  & 2020 & 111  & 111   & 111 & 11 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

As shown below.
In the first picture, the indentation of the captionof is affected.
In the second figure, the indentation is normal after commenting out the caption.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Why not use a `table` environment?

Comment: The `table` environment caused an overflow problem, the words in the table could not be displayed.

Comment: @YANGQ - Please provide a standalone example with a `table` environmment that generates the "overflow problem" behavior you mention in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

I get it!
Add the `\usepackage{ltablex}%Table package extensions` and delete `\captionof{table}{11111}\label{11}` ,add `\caption{111}\label{11}\\` in the `tabularx`
like this:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{sssbbbs}
\caption{111}\label{11}\\
    \toprule
    11   & 111  & 11  & 1111  & 11  & 11   & 11  \\ [0.5ex]
    \midrule
111   & 111 & 2020 & 111 & 111  & 111  & 111  \\
111 & 111  & 2020 & 111  & 111   & 111 & 11 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but your answer raises more questions than it answers [pun intended]. For instance, why are you using the `ltablex` package if you don't intend to use the `tabularx` environmentn with at least one `X`-type column? How or where is the `s` column type defined?

Comment: I'm just trying to give an example of how to add caption without affecting indentation.